# which version of spring data couchbase is compatible with sdk 3.x?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

My project is on spring boot version 1.5.20.relaease and spring-data-couchbase version is 2.2.20.release. I want to move to sdk 3 then which version of spring boot and spring-data-couchbase I should use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.3.x or higher
Spring Data Couchbase 4.x

The following versions are defaults:

```
Spring Boot          Spring Data Couchbase     Couchbase SDK
2.4.0 (jdk1.8+)      4.1.1                     3.0.9
2.6.0 (jdk1.8+)      4.3.0                     3.2.3
2.7.8 (jdk1.8+)      4.4.7                     3.3.4
3.0.2 (jdk17+)       5.0.1                     3.4.1
```

Comment: Thanks John, Do you know how to find out which sdk version spring-data-couchbase uses internally ?

Comment: I have updated by answer with some default versions of couchbase sdk for spring boot versions.

Comment: Thanks @John , Its very helpful. Does spring-data-couchbase jar internally uses couchbase sdk to connect to Couchbase database ? If that is true then Is there any way to verify which sdk version is being used in spring data couchbase jar ?

Comment: Yes it does point to the couchbase client jar. Easiest way to see versions it to look at the maven page for https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-couchbase/5.0.2 - see the "Compile Dependencies"

Comment: Hi @John, Do you know how to connect to couchbase db using application.yaml  if we have different environment like dev and prod. any reference will be helpful. I am using spring-data-couchbase in my spring boot (2.x) application.

Comment: You need to use different spring profiles and different application.properties/yml - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html ignore the bit about public class ProductionConfiguration